# Different methods of evaluating $\int\sqrt{a^2+x^2}dx$:

Tags: calculus, integration

I am looking for an elegant way like this [Different methods of evaluating $\int\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx$:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694853/different-methods-of-evaluating-int-sqrta2-x2dx) to solve $\int\sqrt{a^2+x^2}dx$ without using trignometric identities such as x=atanp

Comment: You realize your link directs us to **this same** question...?

Comment: @DonAntonio I get "404 - Page not found" from the link.

Comment: It is because question 694893 is this very question, @DanielFischer. You can type this nuber in the upper right "search" box and you'll be redirected here...

Comment: @ DonAntonio, I have updated my question..

Comment: @DonAntonio No, this one is `http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696177`. The search leads back here presumably because that id doesn't appear anywhere else on the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pretty much recycle the derivation used in the answer you linked to. Start by integratring by parts, and rearrange:

$$\int \sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx = x\sqrt{x^2+1}-\int x\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx\\
 = x\sqrt{x^2+1}-\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx\\
 = x\sqrt{x^2+1}-\int\frac{x^2+1-1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx\\
 = x\sqrt{x^2+1}-\int\frac{x^2+1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx + \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx\\
 = x\sqrt{x^2+1}-\int\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx + \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx\\
\implies 2\int \sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx = x\sqrt{x^2+1}+\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx\\
\implies \int \sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx = \frac12x\sqrt{x^2+1}+\frac12\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx\\
\implies \int \sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx = \frac12x\sqrt{x^2+1}+\frac12\sinh^{-1}{x}+C$$

Comment: @ David H,good one.+1, but the solution goes as if we know the answer beforehand...

Answer (score 0):

Attempted different answer.  Work with $x\ge 0, a \ge 0$.  Write
$$
F(a) = \int_0^u \sqrt{x^2+a^2}\;dx
$$
for fixed $u$.  Then compute
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \;\sqrt{a^2+x^2} = \frac{a}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}
$$
so
$$
F'(a) = \int_0^u \frac{a}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\;dx = 
-a\log a +a u\log\left(a + \sqrt{a^2+u^2}\right)
$$
(assuming you know how to do this integral).  Also $F(0) = u^2/2$.  So integrate this with respect to $a$, use $F(0)$ to get the "constant":
$$
F(a) = \frac{-\log  \left( a \right) {a}^{2}+\log  \left( u+\sqrt {{a}^{2}+{u}^{2}}
 \right) {a}^{2}+\sqrt {{a}^{2}+{u}^{2}}u}{2}
$$
Check that $\frac{d}{du}$ of this is $\sqrt{a^2+u^2}$.